# Could Recaptcha Enteprise be replaced by Play Integrity API?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, recaptcha-enterprise, google-play-integrity-api

I was reading about two technologies - Recaptcha Enteprise and Play Integrity API. As far as I read correctly they are both based on machine learning and are preventing from bot accounts and other fake movements. Is that correct? Are they working similar and I should implement only one technology in my mobile app?

I would love to have a knowledge about this and learn more.

Answer (score 1):

If your mobile app will be running in IOS devices, then reCaptcha Enterprise will be more recommended than Play Integrity API.
 
[reCAPTCHA Enterprise](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise) is Google’s online fraud detection service that leverages more than a decade of experience defending the internet. [reCAPTCHA Enterprise](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/introducing-recaptcha-enterprises-mobile-sdk-to-help-protect-ios-android-apps) can be used to prevent fraud and attacks perpetrated by scripts, bot software, and humans. When installed inside a mobile app at the point of action, such as login, purchase, or account creation, reCAPTCHA Enterprise can block fake users and bots while allowing legitimate users to proceed. 
To provide more complete coverage for native mobile iOS and Android applications, we’re announcing the general availability of the reCAPTCHA Enterprise Mobile SDK. Designed with digital-first and mobile-first organizations in mind, the new Mobile SDK fully integrates reCAPTCHA Enterprise’s frictionless experience on end-users’ mobile devices.
 
The [Play Integrity API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/overview) helps protect your apps and games from potentially risky and fraudulent interactions, such as cheating and unauthorized access, allowing you to respond with appropriate actions to prevent attacks and reduce abuse.
When your app or game is used on a device that runs Android 4.4 (API level 19) or higher, the Play Integrity API provides a signed and encrypted response that includes the following information:

- **Genuine app binary:** Determine whether you're interacting with your unmodified binary that Google Play recognizes.
- **Genuine Play install:** Determine whether the current user account is licensed, which means that the user installed or paid for your app or game on Google Play.
- **Genuine Android device:** This tells you whether your app is running on a genuine Android device powered by [Google Play services](https://developers.google.com/android).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was thinking about Android application mentioning Play Integrity API. In case of iOS of course recaptcha is right. I think while working on bussiness application the reCaptcha can be good. Or maybe connection of recaptcha + Integrity API.

Answer (score 1):

The Play Integrity API (PIA) focuses on device/OS/app integrity (is this a real device? with a stock OS? and the app was installed from the play store and isn't tampered with?). The reCAPTCHA SDK is an additional layer on top of PIA (under the hood it will also call PIA for you) that provides context specific behavioral analysis, with additional protections for account related actions and credit card transactions. So you'll always get better protection by using the reCAPTCHA SDK.

The situation is similar on iOS, where reCAPTCHA also makes use of the platform provided App Attest API (similar to PIA), but layers additional protections on top.